# SugarCRM 6 - Create an email address-like field to a module

Tags: dynamic, field, sugarcrm

I need to create an email-like field in SugarCRM i.e. one primary value and the ability to add more values dynamically. Anyone who has worked with SugarCRM will know what I'm talking about.

Has anyone done anything similar to this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking from my experience with SugarCRM Community edition (the paid version might be different), the email field appears to be a special field you can't clone using the Admin > Studio.  Email Addresses also are not available as a [Field Data Type](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/5.1/-docs-Administration_Guides-CommunityEdition_Install_Admin_Guide_5.1-System_Administration.4.6.html#1227210) when adding fields using the Studio.  You could create a Text or Drop Down field, but it won't have the special handling for email addresses as you'd expect.

I believe you'll need to hack at the source code to get it done.  This [forum thread](http://www.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=47008) has some sample code you might want to try.  Also try asking your question on the SugarCRM forums.